# Can I ask about how to advertise for a community event?

Tags: discussion

I've been asked to help with advertising a food festival at a community religious institution on social media. I've got a question about ways we can approach that optimally, but wasn't sure whether this would be topical for Community Building. I know that a physical community would be topical, but is *figuring out how to advertise an to non-affiliated community members* on topic?

Answer (score 5):

I'd think so as it's difficult to grow a community without advertising and even if it is building a broader community than trying to get members, you are still building up the overall community in your area, so it's still group building.